# How to use DataGridComboBoxColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I created a `DataGrid` and added a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` programmatically.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private DataGridComboBoxColumn weightColumnChar = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
    ObservableCollection<int> mComboBoxValues;
    public ObservableCollection<int> ComboBoxValues
    {
        get { return this.mComboBoxValues; }
        set { this.mComboBoxValues = value; }
    }//end property
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mComboBoxValues = new ObservableCollection<int>() {-1, 0, 1 };
    }//end constructor
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        weightColumnChar.Header = "Weight";
        dataGrid_Char.Columns.Add(weightColumnChar);

        weightColumnChar.ItemsSource = ComboBoxValues;
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath(ComboBoxValues[1]);
        weightColumnChar.SelectedItemBinding = binding;
    }//end method
    private void dataGrid_Char_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }//end method
    //Opens ComboBox on first click
    private void dataGrid_Char_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OriginalSource.GetType() == typeof(DataGridCell))
        {
            DataGrid grd = (DataGrid)sender;
            grd.BeginEdit(e);
        }//end if
    }//end method
}//end class
```

I added an `ItemsSource` to it and retrieve the values from an `ObservableCollection`.

The values from the collection are shown in runtime.

My problem is that if I select a value from the `ComboBox` this vlaue isn't selected and displayed afterwards. What am I doing wrong?

And I also want to select a default value. How does that work?

Please explain programmatically and not in XAML!

Would be great if anybody could help me.

Thanks!!!

Comment: There is a reason to not use XAML ?

Comment: My Problem is, that the changes aren't shown in the comboBoxColumn.
So I think it has something to do with the right binding.
I can't do this in XAML because I added the dataGridComboBoxColumn programmatically, so I don't have it in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you haven't shown what your underlying collection is that is bound to the DataGrid.

You'll need something like `DataGrid.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();` (it has to be a collection that supports change notification, thus I chose ObservableCollection).

Secondly you are binding the `ComboBox.SelectedItemBinding` to the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` which is nonsense. `ComboBox.ItemsSource` is the collection of values you can choose from, `ComboBox.SelectedItemBinding` (I would actually use `ComboBox.SelectedValueBinding`) is the "path" to the underlying data source that contains/reprsents the final value (eg. **MyClass.IntProperty**). So you select a value from a collection and assign that to some data item (you cannot assign it back to the collection where you select from).

PS! In case you later use something that resembles a KeyValuePair (eg. Id; Name) as your `ComboBox.ItemsSource`, then you set `ComboBox.SelectedValuePath = Id; ComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = Name;`. **MyClass.IntProperty** would contain the **Id** value in such a case.